# Not Mapped to a Single Property Exception in JPA Mapping

Tags: java, jpa

Am having two models named Style and StyleExp with thier respective PK classes and am using **JPA** for mapping.

The Style class contains four variables namely pid, Sname, Screen, StyleId. and the class StyleExp has the varibales named StyleId,EId, sno,exp.

In the class Style `pid`, `Sname`, `Scrn` are primary keys and in the class `StyleExp`, `StyleId`, `EId` are the primary keys. Am having one to many relation between these two classes.

I have provided the mapping like the following in **Style** class,

```
@Entity(name="Style")
@Table(name="Style")
@IdClass(StylePk.class)
public class Style implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private String pid;
    @Id 
    private String Sname;
    private String styleId;
    .....
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.Lazy, mappedBy="style")
    protected List<StyleExp> styleExp;
}
```

In the class STyleExp I have provided the Mapping as follows,

```
@Entity(name="StyleExp")
@Table(name="StyleExp")
public class StyleExp implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private String styleId;
    @Id
    private String eId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="styleId", 
                referencedColumnName="styleId",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    })
    protected Style style;
}
```

But when Am running these code as getting the List of StyleExp from Style class as

```
Style style = styleDao.getStyle(pid, Sname, Scrn)
List<StyleExp> styleExpList =  style.getStyleExp();
```

It throws the following error

**causedBy : org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnName(styleId) of StyleExp.style referencing model.Style not mapped to a single property**

So please kindly let me know what mistake am doing? and one more doubt for me is non primary key and primary key OneToMany and ManyToOne mapping is possible in JPa?
Because of the non primary key mapped to primary key is the problem in the above situation?

Kindly help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: I have added the code in my post. kindly check.

Comment: Your mapping doesn't make much sense. If styleId, in StyleExp, is sufficient to uniquely identify a Style, then it should be the unique identifier of Style, and pid shouldn't be part of it. My advice: avoid composite keys like the plague. Use single-column, purely technical, autogenerated IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. I will try by this method

Comment: Thanks Nizet. I have tried by marking styleId with @Id in Style class. It worked

Answer (score 0):

I have tried by the following for OneToMany mapping between Style and StyleExp

```
@Entity(name="Style")
@Table(name="Style")
public class Style implements Serializable{
    private String pid;
    private String Sname;
    @Id 
    private String styleId;
    .....
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.Lazy, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="styleId", referencedColumnName="styleId" insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    protected List<StyleExp> styleExp;
}
```

In the class StyleExp I have provided the Mapping as follows,

```
@Entity(name="StyleExp")
@Table(name="StyleExp")
public class StyleExp implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private String styleId;
    @Id
    private String eId;
}
```

By using the above code I can map the above two tables

Answer (score 0):

You should only use @Id for primary key in your parent class **Style**.
Other columns that you want to set it as unique, then doing as below:

```
  // primary key
    @Id
    @Column(name = "pid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String pid;
    // unique key
    @Column(name = "styleId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String styleId;
```

Then in your **StyleExp**  class, you can map to the unique column **styleId** in Style class as below

```
 // you are referencing to unique column in parent table    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "styleId", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "styleId")
        protected Style style;
```

The "*referencedColumnName*" is used when you want to map to a none primary column in parent table.

Anyway, no need to use multiple @Id in a table/model class.